# magento search form and jQuery conflitcs

Tags: jquery, html, magento

I am using magento for my online store but I have come across and issue with adding jQuery to my page. When I add:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It makes the search form field in my header stop working. I have tried implementing noConflict to my code but to no avail. The jquery I am using is flexSlider:

```
    $(function(){
      SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    });
    $(window).load(function(){
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        start: function(slider){
         $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
      });
    });
```

Can I get some advice on how to implement noConflict properly, or if this is even the direction I need to go to get this search form back up and running. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

no confolict jquery helped me out

```
<script defer src="http://dev.tavik.com/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/homepage/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    start: function(slider){
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }
  });
});
```